# Dependent questions in SPSS

Tags: spss, survey

I have questions in a survey that are dependent on other questions, i.e. nested questions. How do I enter those into SPSS?

Example:

```
What do you like about Coca-Cola?
1. It tastes the best
2. It's cheap and popular
3. It has a great reputation
(If no. 1 was selected)
Is that because...
1. It has a strong flavor
2. It has a different flavor than Pepsi
```

How can I link these two questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the last two as their own variables. Use a user-define code to specify responses that did not pick "it tastes the best." Like the pic below. The value "-8" can be interpreted as "N/A".

[image]

In the variable view, click on the missing value cell for the two branched questions and assign "-8" (the value I picked, you may pick yours as long as this value is not one of them valid answers). Like this:

[image]

Then in frequency analysis you will see the sample size will be correctly displayed:

[image]

---

If you're familiar with syntax file and would like to document this change, you can use this syntax to achieve the same effect:

```
MISSING VALUES flavor different (-8) .
EXECUTE .
```

For more, see [here](http://www.unige.ch/ses/sococ/cl///spss/vprop/missval.html) and the SPSS online help on "MISSING VALUES".

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need, thanks! Why was it voted negatively?

Comment: Don't encourage working without [syntax](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-syntax-six-reasons-you-should-use-it/). This holds especially for dictionary modifications since these aren't even appended to your [journal file](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/five-reasons-for-not-relying-on-the-journal-file/).

Comment: @RubenGeert Thanks for the comment. I have added the syntax line to the answer.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight: thanks! I'm a bit of a hard-liner on this one: seen too many people who had to do their entire projects all over again because they couldn't say for sure what *exactly* they had done with their data. Very unprofessional. Running commands directly from the GUI is a recipe for disaster but many novice users learn this the hard way.